# Button click no longer works after typing into textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox that I would like to add text to by keyboard, as well as mix in some pre defined phrases from a drop down box. When I first come to the page there is no problem adding the phrases into the textbox, but once I type something in the button stops working

The HTML is:

```
  <div class="tab-pane" id="message">
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="send_message" placeholder="Enter text ...">      </textarea>
  <a href="#message" class="btn btn-large btn-info"  data-toggle="tab">Add Phrase</a>
   <label for=message_list>message_list</label><select id=message_list><option>Hi There.</option><option>How Are You?</option></select>  </div>
```

My jquery is:

```
$('#message').on("click", "a", function(){
.......
..........

else if( $(this).is(":contains(Add Phrase)") )  {
        $('#send_message').append($('#message_list').text());
    }
});
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `val` to set the value of `textarea`
And `val` to access the select value.

You were trying to use `append` on a form element.

```
$('#send_message').append($('#message_list').text());
```

supposed to be

```
$('#send_message').val($('#message_list').val());
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Yz5tp/2/)**

```
$('#message').on("click", "a", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).is(":contains(Add Phrase)")) {
        var $message = $('#send_message')
            previousText = $message.val();
        var currText = previousText + ' ' + $('#message_list').val();
        $('#send_message').val(currText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, That worked! Can I ask why you inserted e.preventDefault()? - Best Regards, Bill

Comment: You are welcome. I added preventDefault so that the link would not be followed which is the default action of the anchor